# CodeIgniter $route don't work in CI 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

The CodeIgniter Routing dont work,
Im trying to route:

```
$route['Kayit'] = "Kayit/index";
```

localhost:8090/Kayit/ result = 404 Page Not Found

And it doesnt work. Can someone help me?

My route.php file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['default_controller'] = 'Sayfa/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'Sayfa/view/$1';
$route['Sayfa/'] = 'Sayfa/view/';

$route['Kayit/'] = "Kayit/index";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'Sayfa/view/$1';
```

At the end line since wildcard placeholder intercepts other routes.
Like:

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['default_controller'] = 'Sayfa/view';
$route['Sayfa'] = 'Sayfa/view';
$route['Kayit'] = "Kayit/index";

$route['(:any)'] = 'Sayfa/view/$1';// (:any) wildcard catcher must go at the end
```

Also, you are good to remove trailing slashes from routes.

From [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#wildcards):

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

Comment: Can u descibe better please ? I cant understand :/

Comment: @MuhammedÇağlarTUFAN Try this way.